# Workspace opens previous files even with settings disabling it

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open VSCode with **`code ./`** to open my project folder, it somehow remembers the last files I had open and keeps them all open.

I want it to open a completely empty / new session when I open it, with ONLY the project folder in the left `EXPLORER` section.

From other questions here on stack overflow I saw that I needed to set certain settings. I did just that and yet the problem persists. These settings are in my **`Ctrl + ,`** settings menu labeled **`USER SETTINGS`** where it says "*Place your settings here to overwrite the Default Settings.*"

Below are my settings and my version number and OS info.

My settings:
    
    `{
        "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.detectIndentation": false,
        "window.zoomLevel": 0,
        "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": false,
        "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
        "window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on",
        "window.restoreWindows": "none",
        "files.hotExit": "off"
    }`

My Version:
    
    `Version 1.21.1
    Commit 79b44aa704ce542d8ca4a3cc44cfca566e7720f1
    Date 2018-03-14T14:46:30.761Z
    Shell 1.7.9
    Renderer 58.0.3029.110
    Node 7.9.0
    Architecture x64`

My OS:
    
    `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
    Memory: 15.4 GiB
    Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 4 
    Graphics: Intel® Haswell Mobile
    OS-Type: 64-bit
    Disk: 475.5 GB
    Hardware: Lenovo Thinkpad T450`

Comment: How about just 'code .'  without the slash?  Does that work better?

Comment: Nope using `code .` seems to still show any tabs that have been double-clicked / set active from previous session.